# OpenCV добавления текста и аудио дорожки к видео

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

Добрый день!
Делаю программу для создания видео при помощи Qt и OpenCV. Если я обладаю правильными сведениями при помощи OpenCV нельзя добавить к видео текст. Как, сделав видео из последовательности картинок, можно добавить к нему текст или аудио?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю OpenCV вы используете для распознавания образов. Для самого создание видеофайла рекомендую использовать ffmpeg. Вот статья о том как записать видеофайл с видео и аудио дорожкой ["Запись видеофайла с помощью ffmpeg"](http://unick-soft.ru/article.php?id=20).

Насчёт текста, то вам необходимо создать картинку с нужным вам текстом. Для этого обычно используют Freetype (статья немного не о том, но в ней есть пример как рендерить [текст с помощью Freetype](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277525/)). Но если вы разрабатываете под Windows, то можно использовать WinGDI ([Пример можно найти в этой статье](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/gdi/)).

Comment: Не подскажите, где почитать про вывод видео при помощи ffmpeg и Qt?

Comment: С помощью ffmpeg вам необходимо декодировать файл, т.е. получить отдельные кадра (http://unick-soft.ru/article.php?id=10). А с помощью Qt просто вывести кадры. Это ничем не отличается от вывода отдельных картинок (QImage::loadFromData) и отображение QImage на форму.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо

Comment: А как подключить ffmpeg к QtCreator не подскажите?

Comment: Судя по всему тут много статей про это: https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=ffmpeg+QtCreator&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 вы можете выбрать наиболее подходящую